# MVC3 - Two models in one View - Error - How to classify

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, class, asp.net-mvc-3, models

I would like to use two models in one view. For that I have the following set up. 
In a single .cs file  I have the following model code:

```
public class Class1   
{
   //List of atttributes 1.
}

public class Class2   
{
   //List of atttributes 2.
}


 public class ParentView
{
   public Class1 Class1{get; set;}
   public Class2 Class2{get; set;}

}
```

To make use of these two classes in one view I reference

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ParentView>
```

in the View .cshtml page. and In my view code there is this code that is breaking up .. I get an error saying - "The models.parentview does not have a definition of Class1Attribute and no extension method.....etc.." How can I classify the statement below so that it recognizes the attribute.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
  {

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1Attribute)

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1Atttribute)    


  }
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful tips.

Comment: When I made this change, it was recognizing the attributes (no red underline squiggly anymore)... but I am getting this error message. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Class1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.ParentView]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1.Class1Attribute)
```

Do you have multiple ParentViews in your Model? If not then you can just have

```
@model Project.Models.ParentView
```

Then reference your Class Attributes as

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Class1.Class1Attribute)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Class2.Class2Attribute)
```

Comment: When I made this change, it was recognizing the attributes (no red underline squiggly anymore)... but I am getting this error message. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Class1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.ParentView]'

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Class1.Class1Attribute)
```

Alternatively you could do something like

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Class1)
 {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1Attribute1)

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1Attribute2)    

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your properties are called `Class1` and `Class2` =>

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Class1.Class1Attribute)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Class2.Class2Attribute)
```

or even better use display templates instead of writing any loops:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and then inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ParentView`:

```
@model ParentView
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Class1)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Class2)
```

and inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Class1.cshtml`:

```
@model Class1
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Class1Attribute)
```

and inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Class2.cshtml`:

```
@model Class2
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Class2Attribute)
```

Comment: When I made this change, it was recognizing the attributes (no red underline squiggly anymore)... but I am getting this error message. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Class1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.ParentView]'.

Answer (score 1):

I think your loop should be as follows

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1.Class1Attribute)

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1.Class1Atttribute)    
}
```

I asssumed `Class1Attribute` is a property in `Class1` class